# multiple steps in workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I am very new to Sharepoint world, and learning online and from some books to get as much as possible.

I am making this demo to understand workflow better, but can't progress much.

My situation is, lets say I request to buy some product, my manager sees it and can reject or approves it. If he approves, my request should go to finance team, and they can proceed it onwards, from finance team to logistics team and I get my product.

Till now, using Approval Workflow, I am able to send request from me till my manager, but I don't  how can he now forward it to Finance team ? Do I need to design another workflow for this ? Or should I program Workflow for this purpose ?
I also have got an option to see what is the status of the request ? When I first start this request, it is Open. When manager approves it is Approved. Now when he change Open to Approved, I want to trigger workflow from Manager to Finance, how can this be done ?

A little tip that can help me get going with this Workflow would be very useful.
Or if you have some suggestions for nice workflow tutorial for beginners, that would be very helpful too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to design another workflow for this

Sorry, but yes, absolutely.

You can try first with SharePoint Designer. From your description it sounds feasible.
If not, you will end up coding it with visual Studio. In this case, good luck, it can be a bit difficult to construct your first workflow.

Comment: Does that mean there will be many workflows for a process like this ? ie workflow from me to manager, another workflow from manager to Finance, and so on ?

Comment: keep it simple for the moment, by constructing a simple unique workflow, but with several "steps" corresponding to a user action

Comment: Hi Steve, can you please explain that in more detail. Sorry, I am total new to this SP Workflow.

Comment: @new_sp_guy: sorry, it's a so vast subject that it cannot be covered here (it's the purpose of SO). But in few words, if you use SPD, you will have to define steps for each user interaction. EAch user interaction is build with a "ask someone to do something activity" (don't remember the englush translation). After each task, use the user input to either change steps, send email, etc.

Comment: Thanks Steve very much. Will look into SPD in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely construct such a workflow using SharePoint Designer 2007, which is a free download from Microsoft's web site. In particular, you can pause the workflow until the approving manager approves or disapproves the request. Then depending on the manager's response, you can have the workflow "send" your request on to the next department.